# How do you learn and understand Vedas? What is the proper method if I can't go to a vedpathshala?

Tags: scripture, vedas

I have tried reading the vedas and it didn't make any sense to me. It just seemed like praises to vedic deities. Later I came to know that you have to learn about vedas from a proper Vedacharya. But I am not in the position to go to a vedpaathshala now, I have a lot of responsibilities.

So what can I do if I want to learn and understand vedas better?

Comment: one has to decide what one needs to do, if you want you can attend a university which teaches

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow There is a difference between what one WANTS to do and what one NEEDS to do. I can very well resonate with what the OP wants and sadly, I do not have any answer to this because I also have the same question. I want to learn about rich history of Hinduism but not at the cost of my daily-life where I have a lot of other responsibilities.